# HTML Email Newsletter - spacing in outlook 2007/2010

Tags: html, email, outlook

I'm coding a HTML email newsletter and I'm getting very weird spacing issues for my tables in Outlook 2007 and 2010

My code which works fine in all other clients is here:

```
   <table width="575" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
<td bgcolor="#0054a4" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px"><a href="http://www.lgfhfghfhfhfghf" target="_blank" style="font-family:Myriad Pro, Verdana, Georgia; font-size:30px; line-height: 34px; font-style:normal; color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;"><center>
      <span style="font-weight:bold;">register</span> for <span style="font-style:lighter;color:#fce000;">mkk</span><span style="color:#fce000; font-weight:bold;"> 56565464646 </span><span style="font-weight:normal; text-decoration:underline;">click here</span></strong>
</center></a></td></tr>



   <tr>
   <td bgcolor="#fce000" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:15px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px"><a href="http://www.fgdfgdg"" target="_blank" style="font-family:Myriad Pro, Verdana, Georgia; font-size:30px; line-height: 30px; font-style:normal; color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;"><center>
      <span style="font-style:lighter;color:#0054a4;">lll</span><span style="color:#0054a4; font-weight:bold;"> ffgfgf </span><span style="font-weight:normal; color:#000000; text-decoration:none;">is proudly sponsored by</span></strong>
     </center></a></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#0054a4" style="padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px"><a href="http://www.gdfgdfgdf" target="_blank"><img name="fgdgfg" src="http://fgfdgdgdg" width="575" height="76" style="font-size:20px; color:#fce000;" alt="fgfdgdfgdfg" border="0"/></a></td>
   </tr>
      </table>

  <table bgcolor="#0055a5" align="center" width="575" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" bgcolor="#0055a5" valign="top"><img src="http://www.fdgfdgdfgdfgdf.png" height="50" width="50" alt="gggggg" align="top" border="no" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;" /></td>



                        <td align="right" bgcolor="#0055a5" valign="top" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:30px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;line-height:20px;color:#fce000;" ><span style="font-weight:bold;color:##fce000;" >gfrtryrtytryrtyrty</span><br />
                          rtrtrtrtertretertetertertertertertertertetert <font style="text-decoration:none;">tertetertetetet</font>
                          <a href=mailto:fgdfgdfgdgdfgfdstyle="color:#fce000; text-decoration:none;" >rtdfgdfgdfgdfg</a> / <a href="http://www.fgdfgdfgdgdgdf" target="_blank" style="color:#fce000;text-decoration:none;">www.fgfgdfgfgd/expo</a><br />

                         <strong> To unsubscribe from this newsletter </strong><a href="http://$UNSUB$" style="color:#fce000; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline" >click here</a>

                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
```

[screen shot of weird outlook spacing here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVH4x.png)

[screenshot of working email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7cpX.png)

if anyone can help please do as its driving me mad!

Answer (score 0):

Don't wrap the `<center>` tag inside an `<a>` tag... Outlook uses MS Word to render HTML (god knows why) and so it has a LOT of restrictions on how you can structure your markup. Just move the link inside the `<center>` tag an it should work fine (I tested this):

```
<table width="575" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#0054a4" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px"><center>
        <a href="http://www.lgfhfghfhfhfghf" target="_blank" style="font-family:Myriad Pro, Verdana, Georgia; font-size:30px; line-height: 34px; font-style:normal; color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;"> <span style="font-weight:bold;">register</span> for <span style="font-style:lighter;color:#fce000;">mkk</span><span style="color:#fce000; font-weight:bold;"> 56565464646 </span><span style="font-weight:normal; text-decoration:underline;">click here</span></strong></a>
      </center></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#fce000" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:15px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px"><a href="http://www.fgdfgdg"" target="_blank" style="font-family:Myriad Pro, Verdana, Georgia; font-size:30px; line-height: 30px; font-style:normal; color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;">
      <center>
        <span style="font-style:lighter;color:#0054a4;">lll</span><span style="color:#0054a4; font-weight:bold;"> ffgfgf </span><span style="font-weight:normal; color:#000000; text-decoration:none;">is proudly sponsored by</span></strong>
      </center>
      </a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#0054a4" style="padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px"><a href="http://www.gdfgdfgdf" target="_blank"><img name="fgdgfg" src="http://fgfdgdgdg" width="575" height="76" style="font-size:20px; color:#fce000;" alt="fgfdgdfgdfg" border="0"/></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table bgcolor="#0055a5" align="center" width="575" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#0055a5" valign="top"><img src="http://www.fdgfdgdfgdfgdf.png" height="50" width="50" alt="gggggg" align="top" border="no" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;" /></td>
    <td align="right" bgcolor="#0055a5" valign="top" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:30px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;line-height:20px;color:#fce000;" ><span style="font-weight:bold;color:##fce000;" >gfrtryrtytryrtyrty</span><br />
      rtrtrtrtertretertetertertertertertertertetert <font style="text-decoration:none;">tertetertetetet</font> <a href=mailto:fgdfgdfgdgdfgfdstyle="color:#fce000; text-decoration:none;" >rtdfgdfgdfgdfg</a> / <a href="http://www.fgdfgdfgdgdgdf" target="_blank" style="color:#fce000;text-decoration:none;">www.fgfgdfgfgd/expo</a><br />
      <strong> To unsubscribe from this newsletter </strong><a href="http://$UNSUB$" style="color:#fce000; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline" >click here</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a helpful list of quirks in Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013 in how it displays HTML emails: 
http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/tips_and_tricks_outlook_07-13#outlook07-13_tip16

The page includes this tip, which fits with the way you've coded the table:

> Avoid using “margin” or “padding” CSS properties in your TABLE tag.
>   Cellpadding and Cellspacing attributes are generally safe but margin
>   or padding will often be added to every TD within the table.

Hope that helps get to the bottom of it.